# Use of CAS signal in 8259A PIC Cascading

Tags: architecture, x86, operating-system, interrupt, hardware

As far as I understand, the 8259A Cascading works in the following procedures:

- slave 8259A raises a interrupt to master 8259A (e.g. through `IR0`)
- processor 'calls' `INTA` pin on master 8259A
- master set the `INT` pin high to notify the processor of an interrupt and that the interrupt is from a slave 8259A
- the processor read slave 8259A's IO port to get the interrupt vector

My question is that since the processor can directly read/write the slave's I/O port, and none of the other 8259As will do read/write because their CS (chip select) is not activated (address on bus do not match their I/O ports), then why `CAS` signal between the master and the slaves is necessary? i.e. Each slaves can 'know' if they are communicating with the processor without reading `CAS` signal.

#### FYI:

[8259A casecade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYnVq.png)

> **description from the datasheet**:
>
> **CASCADE LINES**:The CAS lines form a private 8259A bus to control a multiple 8259A structure. These pins are outputs for a master 8259Aand inputs for a slave 8259A

I'm not sure if there's something wrong with my understanding, and this problem has troubled me for a long time.

Thanks in advance for any help.